# How to identify why the hadoop job is pending?

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop job which is schedule by oozie and pig scripts, but the problem is the job is always in pending status and I can't see any explicit erros/exceptions in jobtracker/tasktracker logs.

Does anyone have similar experience on how identify the root cause?

here is the log from job tracker, and nothing about this job was found in task tracker log:

```
2012-05-09 14:57:19,552 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobQueuesManager: Job job_201205091453_0007 submitted to queue daily
2012-05-09 14:57:19,552 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Job job_201205091453_0007 added successfully for user 'mapred' to queue 'daily'
2012-05-09 14:57:19,552 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger: USER=mapred  IP=10.40.31.234 OPERATION=SUBMIT_JOB    TARGET=job_201205091453_0007    RESULT=SUCCESS
2012-05-09 14:57:22,966 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInitializationPoller: Passing to Initializer Job Id :job_201205091453_0007 User: mapred Queue : daily
2012-05-09 14:57:24,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInitializationPoller: Initializing job : job_201205091453_0007 in Queue daily For user : mapred
2012-05-09 14:57:24,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Initializing job_201205091453_0007
2012-05-09 14:57:24,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Initializing job_201205091453_0007
2012-05-09 14:57:24,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: jobToken generated and stored with users keys in /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/system/job_201205091453_0007/jobToken
2012-05-09 14:57:24,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Input size for job job_201205091453_0007 = 48. Number of splits = 1
2012-05-09 14:57:24,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: tip:task_201205091453_0007_m_000000 has split on node:/default-rack/hzs-ubt-elou
2012-05-09 14:57:24,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: job_201205091453_0007 LOCALITY_WAIT_FACTOR=1.0
2012-05-09 14:57:24,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Job job_201205091453_0007 initialized successfully with 1 map tasks and 1 reduce tasks.
```

see below screenshot, the problem is the map/reduce task is in pending status for more than 21 hours.

[image: the screenshot of the hadoop webui]

Comment: Do you have any available Map slots? (post a screen shot of the job tracker front page)

Comment: @ChrisWhite, I encountered the same question. I do have free map slots, but some jobs are still pending for quite a long time, say several hours.

Comment: What does the job tracker UI for online task trackers show? Are you using a specific scheduler on your system, are some slots reserved for another queue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look at resourcemanager log. usually you can find useful information in it. then if nothing found, look at namenode log.